# Restricting select to a specific div

Tags: jquery

I have a table and I want to find a specific row and move it to the end. I do that with this code:

```
var failLegend = $(".jqplot-table-legend tbody tr").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == "GA Fails";
}).closest("tr");

failLegend.insertAfter($(".jqplot-table-legend tbody tr:last"));
```

That works fine as long as I have just one table. But I have multiple tables all with the same class, and I end up with all of the "GA Fails" rows from all the tables an the end of the last table (instead of one on each table). Each table is in its own div, and I can get at the div name from the $chart variable:

```
$chart
[
<div id=​"chart_0" style=​"width:​ 95%;​ height:​ 450px;​ position:​ relative;​ " class=​"jqplot-target">​…​</div>​
```

But I can't figure out how to use that in my code so when I find and move the row, it only applies to the specific div in $chart.

Here is the full value of $chart:

```
$chart
[
<div id=​"chart_0" style=​"width:​ 95%;​ height:​ 450px;​ position:​ relative;​ " class=​"jqplot-target">​
<canvas width=​"1300" height=​"450" style=​"position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 0px;​ top:​ 0px;​ " class=​"jqplot-base-canvas">​
<div class=​"jqplot-title" style=​"height:​ 0px;​ width:​ 0px;​ ">​</div>​
<div class=​"jqplot-axis jqplot-xaxis" style=​"position:​ absolute;​ width:​ 1300px;​ height:​ 66px;​ left:​ 0px;​ bottom:​ 0px;​ ">​
<canvas width=​"15" height=​"4" style=​"text-align:​ left;​ position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 22.5px;​ " class=​"jqplot-xaxis-tick">​
<canvas width=​"15" height=​"66" style=​"text-align:​ left;​ position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 49.77777777777778px;​ " class=​"jqplot-xaxis-tick">​
<canvas width=​"15" height=​"4" style=​"text-align:​ left;​ position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 77.05555555555556px;​ " class=​"jqplot-xaxis-tick">​
<canvas width=​"15" height=​"4" style=​"text-align:​ left;​ position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 104.33333333333333px;​ " class=​"jqplot-xaxis-tick">​
<canvas width=​"15" height=​"4" style=​"text-align:​ left;​ position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 131.61111111111111px;​ " class=​"jqplot-xaxis-tick">​
<canvas width=​"15" height=​"4" style=​"text-align:​ left;​ position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 158.88888888888889px;​ " class=​"jqplot-xaxis-tick">​
<canvas width=​"15" height=​"4" style=​"text-align:​ left;​ position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 186.16666666666666px;​ " class=​"jqplot-xaxis-tick">​
<canvas width=​"15" height=​"4" style=​"text-align:​ left;​ position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 213.44444444444446px;​ " class=​"jqplot-xaxis-tick">​
<canvas width=​"15" height=​"4" style=​"text-align:​ left;​ position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 240.72222222222223px;​ " class=​"jqplot-xaxis-tick">​
<canvas width=​"15" height=​"4" style=​"text-align:​ left;​ position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 268px;​ " class=​"jqplot-xaxis-tick">​
<canvas width=​"15" height=​"4" style=​"text-align:​ left;​ position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 295.27777777777777px;​ " class=​"jqplot-xaxis-tick">​
<canvas width=​"15" height=​"4" style=​"text-align:​ left;​ position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 322.55555555555554px;​ " class=​"jqplot-xaxis-tick">​
<canvas width=​"15" height=​"4" style=​"text-align:​ left;​ position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 349.8333333333333px;​ " class=​"jqplot-xaxis-tick">​
<canvas width=​"15" height=​"4" style=​"text-align:​ left;​ position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 377.1111111111111px;​ " class=​"jqplot-xaxis-tick">​
<canvas width=​"15" height=​"4" style=​"text-align:​ left;​ position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 404.3888888888889px;​ " class=​"jqplot-xaxis-tick">​
<canvas width=​"15" height=​"4" style=​"text-align:​ left;​ position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 431.6666666666667px;​ " class=​"jqplot-xaxis-tick">​
<canvas width=​"15" height=​"4" style=​"text-align:​ left;​ position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 458.94444444444446px;​ " class=​"jqplot-xaxis-tick">​
<canvas width=​"15" height=​"66" style=​"text-align:​ left;​ position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 486.22222222222223px;​ " class=​"jqplot-xaxis-tick">​
<canvas width=​"15" height=​"4" style=​"text-align:​ left;​ position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 513.5px;​ " class=​"jqplot-xaxis-tick">​
<canvas width=​"15" height=​"4" style=​"text-align:​ left;​ position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 540.7777777777778px;​ " class=​"jqplot-xaxis-tick">​
<canvas width=​"15" height=​"66" style=​"text-align:​ left;​ position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 568.0555555555555px;​ " class=​"jqplot-xaxis-tick">​
<canvas width=​"15" height=​"4" style=​"text-align:​ left;​ position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 595.3333333333334px;​ " class=​"jqplot-xaxis-tick">​
<canvas width=​"15" height=​"4" style=​"text-align:​ left;​ position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 622.6111111111111px;​ " class=​"jqplot-xaxis-tick">​
<canvas width=​"15" height=​"4" style=​"text-align:​ left;​ position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 649.8888888888889px;​ " class=​"jqplot-xaxis-tick">​
<canvas width=​"15" height=​"4" style=​"text-align:​ left;​ position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 677.1666666666666px;​ " class=​"jqplot-xaxis-tick">​
<canvas width=​"15" height=​"4" style=​"text-align:​ left;​ position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 704.4444444444445px;​ " class=​"jqplot-xaxis-tick">​
<canvas width=​"15" height=​"4" style=​"text-align:​ left;​ position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 731.7222222222222px;​ " class=​"jqplot-xaxis-tick">​
<canvas width=​"15" height=​"4" style=​"text-align:​ left;​ position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 759px;​ " class=​"jqplot-xaxis-tick">​
<canvas width=​"15" height=​"4" style=​"text-align:​ left;​ position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 786.2777777777778px;​ " class=​"jqplot-xaxis-tick">​
<canvas width=​"15" height=​"4" style=​"text-align:​ left;​ position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 813.5555555555555px;​ " class=​"jqplot-xaxis-tick">​
<canvas width=​"15" height=​"4" style=​"text-align:​ left;​ position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 840.8333333333334px;​ " class=​"jqplot-xaxis-tick">​
<canvas width=​"15" height=​"4" style=​"text-align:​ left;​ position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 868.1111111111111px;​ " class=​"jqplot-xaxis-tick">​
<canvas width=​"15" height=​"66" style=​"text-align:​ left;​ position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 895.3888888888889px;​ " class=​"jqplot-xaxis-tick">​
<canvas width=​"15" height=​"4" style=​"text-align:​ left;​ position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 922.6666666666666px;​ " class=​"jqplot-xaxis-tick">​
<canvas width=​"15" height=​"4" style=​"text-align:​ left;​ position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 949.9444444444445px;​ " class=​"jqplot-xaxis-tick">​
<canvas width=​"15" height=​"4" style=​"text-align:​ left;​ position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 977.2222222222222px;​ " class=​"jqplot-xaxis-tick">​
<canvas width=​"15" height=​"4" style=​"text-align:​ left;​ position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 1004.5px;​ " class=​"jqplot-xaxis-tick">​
</div>​
<div class=​"jqplot-axis jqplot-yaxis" style=​"position:​ absolute;​ height:​ 450px;​ width:​ 19px;​ left:​ 0px;​ top:​ 0px;​ ">​
<div class=​"jqplot-yaxis-tick" style=​"position:​ absolute;​ top:​ 366.5px;​ ">​-0.3​</div>​
<div class=​"jqplot-yaxis-tick" style=​"position:​ absolute;​ top:​ 306px;​ ">​-0.2​</div>​
<div class=​"jqplot-yaxis-tick" style=​"position:​ absolute;​ top:​ 245.5px;​ ">​-0.1​</div>​
<div class=​"jqplot-yaxis-tick" style=​"position:​ absolute;​ top:​ 185px;​ ">​-0.0​</div>​
<div class=​"jqplot-yaxis-tick" style=​"position:​ absolute;​ top:​ 124.5px;​ ">​0.1​</div>​
<div class=​"jqplot-yaxis-tick" style=​"position:​ absolute;​ top:​ 64px;​ ">​0.2​</div>​
<div class=​"jqplot-yaxis-tick" style=​"position:​ absolute;​ top:​ 3.5px;​ ">​0.3​</div>​
</div>​
<div class=​"jqplot-axis jqplot-y2axis" style=​"position:​ absolute;​ height:​ 450px;​ width:​ 11px;​ right:​ 257px;​ top:​ 0px;​ ">​
<div class=​"jqplot-y2axis-tick" style=​"position:​ absolute;​ top:​ 366.5px;​ ">​0​</div>​
<div class=​"jqplot-y2axis-tick" style=​"position:​ absolute;​ top:​ 330.2px;​ ">​1​</div>​
<div class=​"jqplot-y2axis-tick" style=​"position:​ absolute;​ top:​ 293.9px;​ ">​2​</div>​
<div class=​"jqplot-y2axis-tick" style=​"position:​ absolute;​ top:​ 257.6px;​ ">​3​</div>​
<div class=​"jqplot-y2axis-tick" style=​"position:​ absolute;​ top:​ 221.3px;​ ">​4​</div>​
<div class=​"jqplot-y2axis-tick" style=​"position:​ absolute;​ top:​ 185px;​ ">​5​</div>​
<div class=​"jqplot-y2axis-tick" style=​"position:​ absolute;​ top:​ 148.7px;​ ">​6​</div>​
<div class=​"jqplot-y2axis-tick" style=​"position:​ absolute;​ top:​ 112.4px;​ ">​7​</div>​
<div class=​"jqplot-y2axis-tick" style=​"position:​ absolute;​ top:​ 76.10000000000002px;​ ">​8​</div>​
<div class=​"jqplot-y2axis-tick" style=​"position:​ absolute;​ top:​ 39.80000000000001px;​ ">​9​</div>​
<div class=​"jqplot-y2axis-tick" style=​"position:​ absolute;​ top:​ 3.5px;​ ">​10​</div>​
</div>​
<canvas width=​"1300" height=​"450" class=​"jqplot-grid-canvas" style=​"position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 0px;​ top:​ 0px;​ ">​
<canvas width=​"982" height=​"363" style=​"position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 30px;​ top:​ 10px;​ " class=​"jqplot-series-shadowCanvas">​
<canvas width=​"982" height=​"363" style=​"position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 30px;​ top:​ 10px;​ " class=​"jqplot-series-shadowCanvas">​
<canvas width=​"982" height=​"363" style=​"position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 30px;​ top:​ 10px;​ " class=​"jqplot-series-shadowCanvas">​
<canvas width=​"982" height=​"363" style=​"position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 30px;​ top:​ 10px;​ " class=​"jqplot-series-shadowCanvas">​
<canvas width=​"982" height=​"363" style=​"position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 30px;​ top:​ 10px;​ " class=​"jqplot-series-canvas">​
<canvas width=​"982" height=​"363" style=​"position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 30px;​ top:​ 10px;​ " class=​"jqplot-series-canvas">​
<canvas width=​"982" height=​"363" style=​"position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 30px;​ top:​ 10px;​ " class=​"jqplot-series-canvas">​
<canvas width=​"982" height=​"363" style=​"position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 30px;​ top:​ 10px;​ " class=​"jqplot-series-canvas">​
<canvas width=​"982" height=​"363" style=​"position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 30px;​ top:​ 10px;​ " class=​"jqplot-highlight-canvas">​
<div class=​"jqplot-highlighter-tooltip" style=​"position:​ absolute;​ display:​ none;​ ">​</div>​
<div class=​"jqplot-cursor-tooltip" style=​"position:​ absolute;​ display:​ none;​ ">​</div>​
<canvas width=​"982" height=​"363" style=​"position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 30px;​ top:​ 10px;​ " class=​"jqplot-zoom-canvas">​
<canvas width=​"982" height=​"363" style=​"position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 30px;​ top:​ 10px;​ " class=​"jqplot-lineRenderer-highlight-canvas">​
<canvas width=​"982" height=​"363" style=​"position:​ absolute;​ left:​ 30px;​ top:​ 10px;​ " class=​"jqplot-event-canvas">​
<table class=​"jqplot-table-legend" style=​"position:​ absolute;​ margin-top:​ 0px;​ z-index:​ 3;​ right:​ 0px;​ top:​ 10px;​ ">​
<tbody>​
<tr class=​"jqplot-table-legend">​
<td class=​"jqplot-table-legend jqplot-table-legend-swatch jqplot-seriesToggle" style=​"text-align:​ center;​ padding-top:​ 0px;​ ">​
<div class=​"jqplot-table-legend-swatch-outline">​
<div class=​"jqplot-table-legend-swatch" style=​"background-color:​ rgb(33, 56, 148)​;​ border-color:​ rgb(33, 56, 148)​;​ ">​</div>​
</div>​
</td>​
<td class=​"jqplot-table-legend jqplot-table-legend-label jqplot-seriesToggle" style=​"padding-top:​ 0px;​ ">​NOVA_NAV_500_10pt_MCD_VL​</td>​
</tr>​
<tr class=​"jqplot-table-legend">​
<td class=​"jqplot-table-legend jqplot-table-legend-swatch jqplot-seriesToggle" style=​"text-align:​ center;​ padding-top:​ 0.5em;​ ">​
<div class=​"jqplot-table-legend-swatch-outline">​
<div class=​"jqplot-table-legend-swatch" style=​"background-color:​ rgb(0, 0, 0)​;​ border-color:​ rgb(0, 0, 0)​;​ ">​</div>​
</div>​
</td>​
<td class=​"jqplot-table-legend jqplot-table-legend-label jqplot-seriesToggle" style=​"padding-top:​ 0.5em;​ ">​GA Fails​</td>​
</tr>​
<tr class=​"jqplot-table-legend">​
<td class=​"jqplot-table-legend jqplot-table-legend-swatch jqplot-seriesToggle" style=​"text-align:​ center;​ padding-top:​ 0.5em;​ ">​
<div class=​"jqplot-table-legend-swatch-outline">​
<div class=​"jqplot-table-legend-swatch" style=​"background-color:​ rgb(255, 154, 0)​;​ border-color:​ rgb(255, 154, 0)​;​ ">​</div>​
</div>​
</td>​
<td class=​"jqplot-table-legend jqplot-table-legend-label jqplot-seriesToggle" style=​"padding-top:​ 0.5em;​ ">​NOVA_NAV_500_10pt_MCD_VL_FS_test​</td>​
</tr>​
<tr class=​"jqplot-table-legend">​
<td class=​"jqplot-table-legend jqplot-table-legend-swatch jqplot-seriesToggle" style=​"text-align:​ center;​ padding-top:​ 0.5em;​ ">​
<div class=​"jqplot-table-legend-swatch-outline">​
<div class=​"jqplot-table-legend-swatch" style=​"background-color:​ rgb(255, 0, 0)​;​ border-color:​ rgb(255, 0, 0)​;​ ">​</div>​
</div>​
</td>​
<td class=​"jqplot-table-legend jqplot-table-legend-label jqplot-seriesToggle" style=​"padding-top:​ 0.5em;​ ">​NA Count​</td>​
</tr>​
</tbody>​
</table>​
</div>​
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer on http://forum.jquery.com/ that works perfectly:

```
var rows = $('.jqplot-table-legend tbody tr', $chart);
rows.filter(function() {
      return $(this).text() == 'GA Fails';
}).closest('tr').insertAfter(rows.last());
```

Thanks everyone for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

get the div, then get it's children, then find the elements you are looking for.  this should do it (untested):

```
$('#$chart').children().find(".jqplot-table-legend tbody tr").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == "GA Fails";
}).closest("tr");
```

Comment: This gives:

Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #$chart 

I tried changing it to  $('#'+$chart) and that gives:

Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object Object]

Comment: Typo here! Supposing $chart is the div id, shoudn't it be $('#' + $chart) ?

Comment: $chart is not the div id, it contains the div id - see my original post for what $chart has. I tried what you're saying and it gives: Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object Object]

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear.  I assumed you were generating this using php.  You said the variable $chart I assumed that part was php.  So you can just include that in the php print statement.  Either way, yes you want to make sure you can get the div id from the $chart variable.

Comment: No PHP here. Just javascript/jQuery. That's what I've been unsuccessfully trying to do - get just the div where the id starts with 'chart_'

Answer (score 0):

Try setting a context:

```
var failLegend = $(".jqplot-table-legend tbody tr", $chart).filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == "GA Fails";
}).closest("tr");

failLegend.insertAfter($("#chart_0 .jqplot-table-legend tbody tr:last"));
```

Comment: I don't want to hard code chart_0 - I want to get the div name from the $chart variable and use that.

Comment: Then perhaps something like this (I don't know if you have other divs within $char)
    failLegend.insertAfter($("#" + $($chart).find(div:first).attr('id') + " .jqplot-table-legend tbody tr:last"));

Comment: Yes, there are multiple divs in $chart and your code is picking the wrong one. I need to do something like this:     failLegend.insertAfter($("#" + $($chart).find('div:first')."[id^=chart_].jqplot-table-legend tbody tr:last"));

 But I can't seem to get the syntax right.

Comment: What about removing the :first?

Comment: Already tried that. It doesn't like the syntax - I'm getting 'unexpected string'

Comment: Perhaps something like this?
failLegend.insertAfter($("#" + $($chart).find(div[id^="chart_"]).attr(id) + " .jqplot-table-legend tbody tr:last"));

Comment: With some quoting that can be made syntactically correct, but it is not returning any elements. I don't think using div[id^="chart_"] is the right thing to do. That returns a div with all the chart_* divs it in. I want just the div that corresponds to the div referenced in $chart

Comment: Post exactly how $chart is defined and we'll figure it out

Comment: Are you talking about the code that generates $chart? That is a few 100 lines of code. Or are you talking about the value in $chart? I have updated my original post to show the fully expanded value of $chart.


To summarize, in $chart there is table with class jqplot-table-legend, and I want to find the row in that table that has a value of "GA Fails" and make it the last row in the table. There may be other jqplot-table-legend tables in divs not included in $chart, and I don't want to do that to those tables - just the one that is part of $chart.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
$(".jqplot-table-legend").each(function(){

    var rows = $(this).find("tbody  tr");
    var failLegend = rows.filter(function() {
      return $(this).text().trim() == "GA Fails";
    });

    failLegend.insertAfter(rows.last());
})
```

**Example :** http://codepen.io/ByScripts/pen/BEfmg

Comment: This is not moving the rows to the bottom.

Comment: Ok I corrected the script (I was using children() instead of find()). I also added a trim() else the comparison didn't work.

Comment: With this I end up with one "GA Fails" row at the bottom of the last table. I want one at the bottom of each table.

Comment: I tried, and re-tried... That works for me. Have you seen my example link? There is 2 tables... and the "GA Fails" rows goes into the end of each table.

Comment: Yes your example works, but my situation is bit different. The divs (chart_0, chart_1, ...) are built one at a time. So it does put the row at the bottom of chart_0, but then when it's doing chart_1 it moves the one from chart_0 to chart_1, and so on. So at then end there's just one on the bottom chart.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming u have the chart_id which u are using in ur div as id(chart_id = chart_0 for first div and chart_1 for second div)

just replace

> var failLegend = $(".jqplot-table-legend tbody tr").filter(function()
>   {
>       return $(this).text() == "GA Fails"; }).closest("tr");
>
> `failLegend.insertAfter($(".jqplot-table-legend tbody
>   tr:last"));`

with

> var failLegend = $("#" + chart_id + ".jqplot-table-legend tbody tr").filter(function()
>   {
>       return $(this).text() == "GA Fails"; }).closest("tr");
>
> failLegend.each(function() {
>          $(this).insertAfter($(this).parent().find("tr:last")) });

Comment: With this I end up with one "GA Fails" row at the bottom of the last table. I want one at the bottom of each table.

Comment: No this adds one "GA Fails" row at the bottom of each table.

Comment: The divs (chart_0, chart_1, ...) are built one at a time. So it does put the row at the bottom of chart_0, but then when it's doing chart_1 it moves the one from chart_0 to chart_1, and so on. So at then end there's just one on the bottom chart.

Comment: in that case can'u just put the above js in a function and call it once your html is rendered i.e. use Body onload Event.

Comment: I probably could, but it's now in the function that creates the chart, and it has the div id, so I would like to figure out how to make it work there.